# angular-nvd3 sparkline and trailing currentValue number

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, nvd3.js

I'm just starting to get to know nvd3.  I'm actually using angular-nvd3 to build a sparkline.  What I'm not finding an option for is how to get rid of the trailing currentValue.  I thought showValues might have been it, but I'm actually seeing no difference.

This plunker shows a sparkline with "23" at the end of it, indicating the last value.  That's what I want to get rid of.

http://plnkr.co/edit/CcLayxryGZJGc5vBNpyB?p=preview

```
$scope.options = {
    chart: {
      type: 'sparklinePlus',
      height: 300,
      showValues: false
    }
  };
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to the style to hide the last value

Make the display of the group with text label none.

```
    <style>
.nv-valueWrap {display:none;}

</style>
```

Working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/aNgQj8IcZAiS2zvTx0uP?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for the style options.  However, while this does hide the number, it leaves white space where the number was.I should be clear, that I'm looking for a way to leave the number out completely so the sparkline fills the chart left to right.

Comment: I take that back.  The chart seems to be rendering without the white space now.  Thanks @Cyril

Answer (score 0):

just set the undocumented* option `showLastValue`

`$scope.options = {
    chart: {
      type: 'sparklinePlus',
      height: 300,
      showLastValue: false,
    }
  };`

* I found this in the "new" documentation for LineChart in the dependant library nvds http://nvd3-community.github.io/nvd3/examples/documentation.html

Here is a working example : 
http://plnkr.co/edit/310OK7vgHuxcXj0GWkpc?p=preview